# Microsoft access query with IIf

Tags: ms-access

I have a combo box with 3 values: "Yes, No, *".  * is intended to represent both yes and no options.

In a query within the criteria box of a field called service. CompletedOn I have placed the below IIf statement:

IIf([Forms]![serviceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown]="Yes",([service].[CompletedOn]) Is Not Null,([service].[CompletedOn]) Is Null)

I am trying to ensure that when yes is selected in the combobox any record which contains a completed on value is shown. If no is selected it is not shown and if * is selected all records are shown. Currently the code is showing no records at all. Could you please advise?

SQL below

```
SELECT customer.CustomerID,
 customer.[Customer Name],
 Equipment.Description,
 Equipment.PurchaseID,
 service.Date,
 service.Fault,
 service.JobNo,
 service.costOfRepair,
 service.ServiceID,
 service.CompletedOn,
 CalloutUrgency.CalloutDescription,
 CalloutUrgency.CalloutUrgencyID,
 service.AgentID,
 agent.Serviceagentname,
 supplier.supplierID,
 supplier.supplierName,
 Equipment.ManufacturerID,
 Manufacturer.[Manufacturer Name]
FROM Manufacturer 
INNER JOIN ((customer 
INNER JOIN (supplier 
INNER JOIN Equipment 
    ON supplier.supplierID = Equipment.SupplierID) 
    ON customer.CustomerID = Equipment.CustomerID) 
INNER JOIN (agent 
INNER JOIN (CalloutUrgency 
INNER JOIN service 
    ON CalloutUrgency.CalloutUrgencyID = service.CalloutUrgencyID) 
    ON agent.AgentID = service.AgentID) 
    ON Equipment.EquipmentID = service.EquipmentID) 
    ON Manufacturer.ManufacturerID = Equipment.ManufacturerID
WHERE (((customer.[Customer Name]) Like [Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![houseDropdown]) 
AND ((service.Date) Between [Forms]![ServiceReportForm].[fromDate] And [Forms]![ServiceReportForm].[toDate]) 
AND ((service.CompletedOn)=IIf([Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown]="Yes",Not Null,Null)) 
AND ((CalloutUrgency.CalloutDescription) Like [Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![urgencyDropdown]) 
AND ((agent.Serviceagentname) Like [Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![serviceagentDropdown]) 
AND ((supplier.supplierName) Like [Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![supplierDropdown])) 
    OR (((service.Date) Between [Forms]![ServiceReportForm].[fromDate] And [Forms]![ServiceReportForm].[toDate]) 
    AND (([Forms]![ServiceReportForm])=" All"));
```

Comment: Can you show your full query? It looks like you are trying to make dynamic sql but iif can't be used like that

Comment: Full query? Do you mean all the other fields and criteria?

Comment: Surely there is more to this query than what you show. There's a table and columns somewhere and a full where clause. Putting that in the question will be very helpful.

Comment: Is there a way I can print this in a readable format? Ie, a single statement? At the moment I'm looking at query editor and there are lots of boxes with different fields and bits of code in them so it's very difficult to show the whole query

Comment: you can change your view from Design View to SQL view in the top left of the ribbon. Or Click SQL in the bottom left of the whole window.

Comment: Thanks, Ive added the full query to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're treating the IIF function as though it were returning a string which is then inserted into your query and the query then executed. However, that's not the order in which things are processed. IIF should return either a value to check against or a boolean itself. replace this

```
((service.CompletedOn)=IIf([Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown]="Yes",Not Null,Null))
```

with this

```
IIf([Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown]="Yes",service.CompletedOn is Not Null,service.CompletedOn is Null)
```

Notice too that I got rid of the `=` because you can't test for null using `=`, you must use `is`.

To return All records when `*` is selected

```
IIF([Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown] = "*"
  ,True
  , IIf([Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown]="Yes"
    ,service.CompletedOn is Not Null
    ,service.CompletedOn is Null))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working.  How can I get it working in the case of "*" being selected in the dropdown?  I'd like to show all records whether completed or not.

Comment: @Simon see my edit. Basically you need to find a way to eliminate any filter on that field.

Answer (score 0):

It must have something to do with the null check syntax and using IIF

Replace this in your SQL

`((service.CompletedOn)=IIf([Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown]="Yes",Not Null,Null))`

With this

`((service.CompletedOn Is Not Null) AND ([Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown]="Yes")) OR ((service.CompletedOn Is Null) AND ([Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown]<>"Yes"));`

Comment: Still a blank report when I try this

Comment: What kind of field is CompletedOn - is it a date? If you run a separate query on the field - does anything show up when you use Is Null in the query - you should show us your full SQL (under View | SQL View), otherwise we're all guessing at what you're doing

Comment: It is a date.  Full SQL added above

Comment: Whoa - you have a lot of InnerJoins and WHERE clauses. Have you troubleshooted your criteria first - do you get any results if your remove the IIF clause?

Comment: Yes, all works as expected without the IIf clause. But then I can't filter by completed job

Comment: It must have something to do with the null check syntax and using IIF ... Replace this `((service.CompletedOn)=IIf([Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown]="Yes",Not Null,Null))`    <\br>With this `(((service.CompletedOn Is Not Null) AND ([Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown]="Yes")) OR ((service.CompletedOn Is Null) AND ([Forms]![ServiceReportForm]![workcompletedDropdown]<>"Yes")))`